# Angular 7: Change button text depending on value (+ ready for translate)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to display a button with different texts. The text should be ready for translate, e.g.

```
  <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="onCancelClick()" [mat-dialog-close]="data" cdkFocusInitial>
    <ng-container
      *ngIf="condition1; else closeBtn">
      <span #cancelBtn i18n="@@cancel">Cancel </span>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-template #closeBtn i18n="@@closeDlg">Close </ng-template>
  </button>
```

This solution works but has the disadvantage that the buttons color is not reflected in the text, i.e. it is displayed as black - but since I use `accent` it should be white.

Using the approach

`<button>{{ (condition1 ? 'Cancel' : 'Close') | translate }}</button>`

Doesn't help much because I have no clue how to get a handle for the translated string.

Isn't there a possiblity without duplicating the `button`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
  <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="onCancelClick()" [mat-dialog-close]="data" cdkFocusInitial>
    <ng-container *ngIf="condition1" i18n="@@cancel">Cancel </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="!condition1" i18n="@@closeDlg">Close </ng-container>
  </button>
```

Comment: Yeah - this worked  - cause I missed that the `span` causes additional troubles :-/ `ng-container` fixes the issue...

Answer (score 1):

```
<button mat-raised-button [ngStyle]="{'color': accent}" (click)="onCancelClick()"[mat-dialog-close]="data" cdkFocusInitial>
<ng-container *ngIf="condition1; else closeBtn" #cancelBtn i18n="@@cancel">
  Cancel
</ng-container>
<ng-template #closeBtn i18n="@@closeDlg">
  Close 
</ng-template>
```

> You can also use [ngStyle] to set color

Comment: please add some explanation to your answer

Comment: Yeah - that's even more appropriate than the accepted answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a conditional class or data attribute to the button, and style with css. E.g.

```
<button 
  mat-raised-button 
  ...
  [ngClass]="condition1 ? 'myClass1' : 'myDefaultClass'"
>
    ...
  </button>
```